# pandas DataFrame edge list to networkX graph object

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, networkx, undirected-graph

I am trying to create an undirected graph from a DataFrame `formatted_unique_edges` - the `'weight'` column will purely be used for edge colouring in downstream visualisation using [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/network-graphs/):

```
    source      target      weight
0   protein_2   protein_3   3
1   protein_2   protein_6   2
2   protein_3   protein_6   2
3   protein_2   protein_4   2
4   protein_2   protein_5   2
5   protein_3   protein_4   2
6   protein_3   protein_5   2
7   protein_4   protein_5   2
8   protein_4   protein_6   1
9   protein_5   protein_6   1
```

The first lines in the linked plotly example, which I am trying to emulate, is:

```
G = nx.random_geometric_graph(200, 0.125)
edge_x = []
edge_y = []
for edge in G.edges():
    x0, y0 = G.nodes[edge[0]]['pos']
    x1, y1 = G.nodes[edge[1]]['pos']
    edge_x.append(x0)
    edge_x.append(x1)
    edge_x.append(None)
    edge_y.append(y0)
    edge_y.append(y1)
    edge_y.append(None)
```

I first convert `formatted_unique_edges` to a Graph, then try to emulate the code above, with some diagnostic print statements:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(formatted_unique_edges, 
                            edge_attr=True) 
#also tried G = nx.random_geometric_graph(200, 0.125) as per plotly example

edge_x = []
edge_y = []
for edge in G.edges():
    print(edge) #('proteinN', 'proteinM')
    print(G.nodes[edge[0]]) #{}
    print(G.nodes[edge[1]]) #{}
    x0, y0 = G.nodes[edge[0]]['pos']
    #####
    #THROWS KeyError: 'pos' if G is from formatted_unique_edges
    #####
    #prints {'pos': [float, float]} if G is from nx.random_geometric_graph
    x1, y1 = G.nodes[edge[1]]['pos']
    edge_x.append(x0)
    edge_x.append(x1)
    edge_x.append(None)
    edge_y.append(y0)
    edge_y.append(y1)
    edge_y.append(None)
```

As stated in the comments, I am getting a `KeyError` from `G.nodes[edge[0]]['pos']`.  I had a look in the spyder variable explorer and `G.nodes._nodes` from `nx.random_geometric_graph` has the format:

```
{0   : {'pos' : [pos_float, pos_float]}, 
 1   : {'pos' : [pos_float, pos_float]},
 ...
 199 : {'pos' : [pos_float, pos_float]}
}
```

Whereas as `G.nodes._nodes` from `formatted_unique_edges` has the format:

```
{'protein_2' : {},
 'protein_3' : {},
 'protein_4' : {},
 'protein_5' : {},
 'protein_6' : {}}
```

This all suggests I am making my `Graph` object from `formatted_unique_edges` incorrectly with `nx.from_pandas_edgelist` - can someone advise how I should be doing it?

Thanks!
Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to generate a [layout](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.layout) for your graph. `random_geometric_graph` generate a graph but not only. It also call a layout to generate the coordinates (pos).

```
# Convert your dataframe to graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(formatted_unique_edges, edge_attr=True)

# Generate the layout and set the 'pos' attribute
pos = nx.drawing.layout.spring_layout(G)
nx.set_node_attributes(G, pos, 'pos')

edge_x = []
edge_y = []
for edge in G.edges():
    x0, y0 = G.nodes[edge[0]]['pos']
    x1, y1 = G.nodes[edge[1]]['pos']
    edge_x.append(x0)
    edge_x.append(x1)
    edge_x.append(None)
    edge_y.append(y0)
    edge_y.append(y1)
    edge_y.append(None)
```

Output:

```
>>> G.nodes._nodes
{'protein_2': {'pos': array([0.5830424, 0.0301945])},
 'protein_3': {'pos': array([-0.42158911,  0.33654032])},
 'protein_6': {'pos': array([0.30069049, 1.        ])},
 'protein_4': {'pos': array([-0.71990583, -0.51877307])},
 'protein_5': {'pos': array([ 0.25776204, -0.84796174])}}
```